# Cannot right click with synaptics touchpad

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, vaio, synaptics, sony

I have a Sony VAIO E14. The touchpad detects all clicks as Left clicks. In Windows 7, pressing on the right side of the touchpad is recognised as a right click.

How can I enable right clicking?

```
greg@greg-SVE14A1C5E:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
...

greg@greg-SVE14A1C5E:~$ grep "TouchPad: buttons:" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[    23.112] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left double triple
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me... Touch anywhere on the screen with two fingers and make a click. In other words place two fingers on the clickpad then press down. I hope this is relevent, since there are so many types of trackpad. If you don't have a click pad I don't know how to do it... I read somewhere that 12.10 was going to fix it, but I am a linux noob, came from Mac and the same "right click" just works, but when I bought this computer (Acer Aspire one 756) It had a "right click" area that doesn't work in Ubuntu.

Comment: Touching anywhere with 2 fingers worked for me but it's not quite the fix I was after. I tried it in Chromium and on the Ubuntu top menu bar but it only worked in Chromium

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind upgrading ubuntu 12.10 supports it by default.